# Serilog ILogger DPI Microsoft ILogger

Tags: serilog

We are making a MCV application to write Logs to the ELkstack.
We need to use Serilog, while using the Microsoft ILogger in the controllers.
How can we make sure the logging is being done by Serilog while using the microsoft extension?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As you define the setting in app settings files in serilog block. So by using the reference like file name, format, path etc using you can get that it's logging by serilog only.

Comment: Well we use the configuration from the Serilog Github Page but when zwe use the basic ILogger _logger private readonly, we get an error on startup:
"InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'StormTroopersDotNetCase.Controllers.ReservationController'."